# Moving to next ViewMontroller with PageController swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have a page viewcontroller where I am displaying a few items and in the main ViewController, I want to be able to move to the next page by using buttons. I have added the viewcontrollers to an array but how to create a function which would be called in next and back button is what puzzled me.

below is my code

```
private var pageController: UIPageViewController!

    lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = {
        let locVC = LocationVC()
        locVC.delegate = self
        let typeVC = TypeVC()
        typeVC.delegate = self
        return [locVC,
                typeVC]
    }() 

private func setupPageController() {

    self.pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    self.pageController.dataSource = self
    self.pageController.delegate = self
    pageController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    addChild(pageController)
    view.addSubview(pageController.view)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        pageController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navView.bottomAnchor),
        pageController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        pageController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        pageController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    pageController?.setViewControllers([controllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false)

}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController? {
        if controllers.count == 0 || index >= controllers.count {
            return nil
        }

        return UIViewController()
    }

    func backBtnClicked() {

        guard currentIndex - 1 >= 0 else { return }
        currentIndex -= 1
        guard let startingViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(index: currentIndex) else { return }
        pageController.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .reverse, animated: false)
    }
```

all viewcontrollers have a variable which is `var pageIndex: Int = 0` this is what I believe would be used to detect the current page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ( e.x go to first vc in pager )

```
pageController.setViewControllers([controllers[index]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: so I put this into a function how would I be able to track the index?

Comment: add an `index` variable same like what in before and after

Comment: `func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController? {
        if controllers.count == 0 || index >= controllers.count {
            return nil
        }

        return UIViewController()
    }` I wrote this in the question